# Why I can't access my account using ssh?

Tags: high-performance-computing

When I try to acess my account in a workstation remotely using my laptop by ssh using the following command:

```
ssh login@10.20.2.X
```

I get the following message in terminal:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.20.2.X port 22: No route to host (X: is a number)
```

I think the problem is because I`m not locally present, the workstation is in another city. When I contacted the responsible in the workstation he said : 'check the configuration of your network card (you must have the range: 10.20.2.x)'

How can I solve this issue, please?

PS: The responsible for the workstation just created the account for me recently and sent me the connection parameters, so I never used this account before.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to either Server Fault SE, or Unix and Linux SE

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin the question won't be welcomed very well on either of those sites, so hopefully that comment doesn't come across as a recommendation for Camilla to ask this question in those places (it would lead to a bad experience!). Camilla can you list for us all the possible reasons for this error message that you've found based on your prior research?

Comment: @NikeDattani Yeah you're right I went to Server Fault as Abdulmuhaymin suggested and the question wasn't welcomed.

Comment: @NikeDattani I edited my question with more information, check them please?

Comment: @Camilla Could you please add more details such as what is the command that you ran, that gave you this error? Also I think it would be good to say if this command was working before for you and if this issue started occuring after you changed something. Perhaps you updated your OS version or something.

Comment: Related questions on AskUbuntu Stackexchange:

1. [Ask_Ubuntu_q1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395045/ssh-connect-to-host-192-168-0-200-port-22-no-route-to-host)

2. [Ask_Ubuntu_q2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129232/cannot-connect-to-ssh-server-port-22-no-route-to-host)

3. [Ask_Ubuntu_q3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/754322/ssh-no-route-to-host)

4. [Ask_Ubuntu_q4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324291/ssh-connect-to-host-port-22-no-route-to-host)

5. [Ask_Ubuntu_q5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53976/ssh-connection-error-no-route-to-host)

Comment: @VandanRevanur I edited my question. Can you check it please?

Comment: @Camilla Shouldn't X be a number ? Something like ssh login@10.20.2.1 or something like that? Also what happens if you do : `ping -c4 10.20.2.X` ?
Is your username called `login` ?

Comment: @VandanRevanur yeah X is a number i'm just hidding it, login isn't my real username. when I do `ping -c4 10.20.2.X`  I get `PING 10.20.2.X (10.20.2.X) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 81.192.249.106 icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded
From 81.192.249.106 icmp_seq=2 Time to live exceeded
From 81.192.249.106 icmp_seq=4 Time to live exceeded

--- 10.20.2.X ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3009ms
`

Comment: Is 10.20.2.X a local IP? If it is, you won't get access to it from another city (even a computer in the same city won't get access if your computer is not connected to the same network). Also, check for the SSH port with the network administrators.

Comment: @Camilla perhaps you need to connect to a particular vpn to access this remote server. And I think the IT contact person should provide you some documentation on how to connect ideally. I advice you to check with them. It is difficult to debug network issues when we don’t have access to the systems and more details about the server etc

Comment: @AbdulMuhaymin it was closed as "off-topic" on ServerFault, so it doesn't "belong" there! Camilla did get some useful feedback in the comments though, but the comments by Camps and Vandan here seem a lot more helpful.

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes, I understand. I retracted the close vote

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the topic is not related to matter modeling but basic unix networking.